# If $V,W$ are vector spaces over $F$ with dimensions $m$ and $n$ respectively, then find the dimension of the space, $Z=\{(v, w): v ∈ V$ and $w ∈ W\}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a field $F.$ Let $Z = \{(v, w): v ∈ V \space \text{and}\space w ∈ W\}$  with the operations $(v_1, w_1)+(v_2, w_2)=(v_1 + v_2, w_1 + w_2)$ and $c(v_1, w_1)=(cv_1, cw_1).$ $Z$ is also a vector space over $F.$ If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces of dimensions $m$ and $n,$ determine the dimension of $Z.$

In this problem, first I assumed $B_1$ and $B_2$ are the bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively. Let $B_1=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_m\}$ and $B_2=\{w_1,w_2,...,w_n\}.$ Next, I considered the set $A=\{(v,0)\in W:v\in B_1\}$ and $B=\{(0,w)\in W:w\in B_2\}.$

I tried to show that $A\cup B,$ is a  basis for $Z.$

This is indeed true, for if, $(v,w)\in Z,$ then,  $\exists$ scalars $b_1,...,b_m,c_1,...,c_n$ such that $v=b_1v_1+...+b_mv_m$ and  $w=c_1w_1+...+c_nw_n.$ Thus, we have, $(v,w)= b_1(v_1,0)+...+b_m(v_m,0) +c_1(0,w_1)+...+c_n(0,w_n).$ So, $Z\subseteq \text{span}(A\cup B).$ This further means $Z=\text{span}(A\cup B),$ as $ \text{span}(A\cup B)\subseteq Z.$

Now, $A\cup B$ is also, linearly independent for if $\exists$ scalars $a_1,...,a_{m+n}$ such that $a_1(v_1,0)+...+a_m(v_m,0) +a_{m+1}(0,w_1)+...+a_{m+n}(0,w_n)=(0,0).$ This means, $a_1v_1+a_mv_m=0$ and $a_{m+1}w_1+...+a_{m+n}w_n=0.$ But  $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_m\}$ and $\{w_1,w_2,...,w_n\}$ are linearly independent subsets of $V$ and $W$ respectively and  hence, $a_1=a_2=...=a_{m+n}=0.$ This proves that $A\cup B$ is a basis for $Z.$

Now, to find the dimension of $Z$ we need  to check the cardinality of $A\cup B$ which is, $m+n-1,$ if $A\cap  B=\{0,0\},$ as $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|.$

This means that $\dim (Z)=|A\cup B|=m+n-1.$

However, the answer given is that   $\dim (Z)=m+n.$ I  am not  getting where did I go wrong?

Comment: $A \cap B$ is empty

Comment: @terran Why? I feel it is, $\{0,0\}.$

Comment: That implies that $0 \in B_1$ and $0 \in B_2$, but $B_1$ and $B_2$ are bases!

Comment: @terran Ah, I missed it. Thanks!